# How can I check if there is a new build the same jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I have a github multibranch pipeline, in declarative format. It is configured to trigger on pushes to pull request branches (ie, branches which are included in pull requests to a target branch, say `main`.

If a new commit comes in before the execution of a previous commit is finished, this will trigger a concurrent build of the pipeline. I want to maintain this behaviour, but **need to know if there is a new pipeline running** in one of the stages.

Ie I want a groovy script step like this pseudo code:

```
if (build_number + 1) is_currently_running
  do one thing
else
  do something else
```

Is there any way to ask Jenkins if build n+1 is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward to do in a script block.  I don't think there's a declarative-native way to do this.

I use this script block to cancel builds for earlier (i.e. outdated) revisions of PRs:

```
script {
  // currentBuild is a Pipeline-builtin variable for accessing the Build object
  // https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference
  def build = currentBuild

  while(true) {
    build = build.getPreviousBuild()

    // exit the loop if we have finished iterating over builds
    // (groovy doesn't have a do...while feature)
    if (build == null) break

    def rawBuild = build.rawBuild

    if (rawBuild.isBuilding()) {
      // abort the build
      rawBuild.doTerm()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can hopefully see, this iterates over **all** previous builds and uses the `isBuilding()` method to find ones that are currently running.

If you want to check later builds instead of previous ones, you can use `getNextBuild()` instead (I believe the API doc is [here](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html), it's been a while since I wrote this so this might be the wrong class).

And if you want to check only one directly adjacent build instead of all earlier/later builds, you can just omit the loop and only call `getPreviousBuild()`/`getNextBuild()` once.